# How do I add a generic sublayout across a few templates without manually adding one by one?

Tags: sitecore

Is it possible to add a sublayout(usercontrol) across a few templates without manually adding one by one to each of the templates?

Currently, we are adding all the common sublayouts to each of the templates _standard values and rendering them. Looking for a better implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a great case for using inheritance with your Data Templates. By inheriting from a "base" template, the other templates can be controlled from a single location - the standard values of the base template.

Alternatively, you can use the "Copy To" feature located in the Presentation > Details dialog to easily copy presentation from one item to another.

The third option is to bake your Sublayout into the Layout by adding it directly to the .aspx or .cshtml file. However, in this scenario, the Sublayout would appear on all items that used that layout, unless it contained logic to conditionally render itself.

Comment: exactly what I wanted, I created a base template but wasn't adding the sublayouts to its Standard values. Adding to the base's stdvalues did the trick for me.

Comment: when I modify the presentation layout details of the derived template, the inheritance doesn't work anymore, is there a work around for that?

Answer (score 1):

To avoid adding the sublayout on each and every template,

Create a Template add all required fields on the same.
in its standard values assign the sublayout.

Inherit this template in all required templates.
This will help in 2 cases.

1. you dont need to create common fields in all the templates
2. you dont need to assign the common sublayout in all the templates.